# How to pull data from postgresql database to my shinyapps.io

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny-server

can shiny apps in shiny apps.io be linked to my postgresql database ? i tried but it gives me error here is my code it works offline but i can't launch it in shiny apps.io

this is the error

> DONE Uploading application bundle...DONE Deploying application:
>   42170... Waiting for task: 32473560   error: Parsing manifest
>
> ############################ Begin Log ##################################
>   
>   ############################# End Log ###################################  Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 32473561 failed: Error parsing manifest: Unsupported locale:
>
> 4409_4409.UTF-8

my short version of  server.r

```
library(e1071)
library(cluster)
set.seed(123)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  library("RPostgreSQL")
  drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
  con <- dbConnect(drv, host='localhost', port='5432', dbname='TESTDB',
                   user='postgres', password='root')
  rk <- dbSendQuery(con,"select * from persons")
  rs<-fetch(rk)

  radioValues <- reactive({
    gender <- input$gender
    if (gender==1){
      rs[rs$gender=="male",]
    } else if (gender==2){
      rs[rs$gender=="female",]
    } else if (gender==3){
      rs
    }

  })

  selectedData <- reactive({
    radioValues()[,input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]

  })
   output$mytable = renderDataTable({
   selectedData()
  })


  dbDisconnect(con)  
})
```

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
          "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))

library("RPostgreSQL")
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, host='localhost', port='5432', dbname='TESTDB',
                 user='postgres', password='root')
rk <- dbSendQuery(con,"select * from persons")
rs<-fetch(rk)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(h1("Clustering Process Dashboard",style='font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif')),
  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxGroupInput('show_vars', 'Select Big 5 features',names(rs)[c(-1,-2)], selected = names(rs)[c(-1,-2,-3,-9)]),
  ),
  mainPanel(

    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput('mytable'))
  )
  )
)
)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Please note that i don't post my full code i just post the code regarding the issue. It's my Final year project so if you want my full code please contact me. I hope you can understand my concern about this. So if u find error any where in this code i apologize in advance.

Comment: You can't do this unless you know the IP address of the shinyapps.io server that is running the Shiny instance, and as what user. The you will have to manage the permissions on your Postgres instance to allow reads from that IP address and that user. Highly discouraged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  I have an application with this configuration (hosted on shinyapps.io and saving/pulling data from a Postgresql database).

However, under the current configuration you've indicated, it won't work.  Here is why: You're running the postgresql server on your own personal machine (host=localhost).   When you run your app as you're developing it (in R Studio?), it works because the local shinyapps server built into R studio is also running on your local machine.   When you deploy your app to shinyapps.io, your database connection string still specifies host="localhost" -- but when it's deployed online, localhost refers to the local server on shinyapps.io; and that server is not running your Postgresql database.  Therefore, you're getting an error.

To get it to work and connect to "my postgresql database" as you've specified, you'd need to change the host from "localhost" to whatever your personal IP address is.  This also means you need to have your local machine open to the internet, as well as the port on which you're running postgresql.  You may be able to do this by configuring your router, if its a personal internet setup.  This is not an ideal solution for many reasons, not least of which is that your app on shinyapps.io will only function while your local machine is running and connected to the internet at the specified IP address.

A better solution is to setup a cloud-based Postgresql hosting solution.  Many companies provide this service (usually for a fee).  Amazon Web Services provides an introductory 12-month free solution for small databases.  Here's a link to a help page, from which you can also explore their services: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html

There's a fair amount of setup/registration steps, but it's also easy to click through the menus and get an instance up and running quickly.  Once you have an instance on the cloud, you'll need to update the database connection information to the cloud.  From there, your shinyapps.io instance can communicate reliably between their server online and the database cloud server online.  You'll then need to doubly-deploy updates when you make changes to the app and to the database: one update deployment to shinyapps.io and, when needed, the update to your database instance.  Be mindful of protecting data entered on either/or your local machine versus through the deployed app that would save data to the cloud server.